# How to change Eclipse output build directory for Android (ie /bin->/build)?

Tags: android, eclipse, build

Androids ant-target and Eclipse both build to the same folder, namely /bin. I especially (or only) wish for the android library projects to be built into another folder than /bin.

This is a relevant, because when doing ant-release I'll loose my build will break. We use eclipse auto-edit-on-save feature, and if I edit a non-compiling file, Eclipse will edit and ruin the file (such as importing android.R instead of local R).

These to Android bugs mention why I cannot just get the ant-build to build in another folder by changing out.dir in library projects ant.properties:

[Android ant-issue1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63578)

[Android ant-issue2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60496)

Comment: At this point, I'd skip Ant and move to the new Gradle-based build system. Not only will you be working on something that represents the future, but it already uses `build/` instead of `bin/`.

Comment: Thx we are considering that, but it seems it is not yet worth our time, as the current ant-build still builds and releases, and switching to Gradle would likely take a lot of effort. But it is a good point, that its also not worth spending long to maintain the old one.